# WAIT or NOWAIT? That is the question. PosgreSQL vs ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

I am migrating from Oracle to postgreSQL and I have a question.
I have used to use the query for oracle  like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = '123' FOR UPDATE WAIT 30"
```

As far as I understand in postgreSQL we have only NOWAT options, so I have changed query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id = '123' FOR UPDATE"
```

Question is, how can I populate some lock timeout? I saw that I could send additional queries, for example

```
set lock_timeout = 30000; or set lock_timeout = ‘30s’;
select for update ...
set lock_timeout = 0;
```

However in this case I am adding 2 additional queries, but I don't want to. Is there any other way to populate some lock timeout?

Comment: In a word,, no.

Comment: And if you will add few more words? ...

Comment: There's not much to add. There is no functionality in postgres to specify a wait timeout as part of FOR UPDATE. Your workaround is about the best you'll get to replicate that functionality, with the caveat that you should use `SET LOCAL lock_timeout` so it affects that transaction only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is possibility to configure lock timeout at posgreSQL server configuration.

Change parameter `lock_timeout = '30s'` in `pgsql/11/data/postgresql.conf`
After that reload configuration or restart postgreSQL

Comment: You don't need to change `postgresql.conf` for that: [`set lock_timeout = '30s'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) will change it for the current session.

Comment: Agree. You need to do this only if you agree to apply this timeouts to all statements. This parameter will affect all sessions.

Comment: As per [documentation](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/lock_timeout/): "Setting lock_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions."